# Android.Support.Wearable.Comapnion.WatchFaceCompanion won't import Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am not using Eclipse. I am currently using Android Studio 1.0.2. I am attempting to complete the creating watch faces tutorial however I am not able to compile due to

`import android.support.wearable.companion.WatchFaceCompanion;` not importing.

I've searched here, and the other questions are for those using Eclipse. I've added all of the sdk build tools. This didn't work. I modified the gradle build items in wear/app and that didn't work.

Edit: I dug into the issue a bit more via the example and I noticed the import is referenced here:

> G:[my_windows_username]\Android\WatchFace\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\classes.jar!\android\support\wearable\companion\WatchFaceCompanion.class

Why isn't this in my new project by default when I attempt to import?

Comment: does your windows username (which is oh so private) have a space character in it?

Comment: @Blundell, my windows username doesn't have a space in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more than likely an issue where you have not added the line:

compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+"

to your build.gradle for your APPLICATION module. This should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with in my watch face application. I solved by installing/updating the Android Wear 2.0.1 version from SDK Manager in Android Studio.

I suggest, check out in build.grandle if there is an error on android.support.wearable.2.0.0 compilation. Then try to install newest SDK tools (wear 2.0.1) and lib (25.0.2)